# cannot convert from system.collections.generic.list to string to Vba.collections

Tags: c#, asp.net, vba, vb6

I want to pass a list of int from C# to a dll written in vb6 . In vb6 the prototype of function is as follows :

```
Public Function FamIdentify(agentList As Collection, strName As String, strIdentifyTemplate As String, strIP As String) As Boolean
```

From C# I am calling this function As follows :

```
public Boolean IdentifyFinger(String name, String SampleModel, String REMOTE_ADDR) 
{ 
List<int> agentList = new List<int>(); 
// insert some element to this list
FamServer.FamApp famApp = new FamServer.FamApp(); 
Boolean flag = famApp.FamIdentify(ref agentList, ref name, SampleModel, REMOTE_ADDR);
 return flag ; 
}
```

For this coding I am facing this error

```
cannot convert from system.collections.generic.list to string to Vba.collections
```

How can I pass list from C# to vb6 ? Please help me .

Comment: Try converting to `System.Collections.ArrayList` instead - this type can be exposed to VBA through the `CreateObject()` method.

Comment: Your comment is not clear to me . Can you explain ?

Comment: Create an `ArrayList` in C#, populate it with the values form your `List`, create an `ArrayList` in the VBA code, pass the `ArrayList` to VBA...

Comment: **or** why not just use the `.toArray()` method and pass as an array instead?

Comment: I will use the concept of array . Just trying with lists . If I am fail to do this with list then I will use array .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection`, add values from `List`, and only then pass it to function. I think, there is no direct cast to `Collection`.

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection agentCollection= new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection();
agentList.ForEach(x=> agentCollection.Add(x));

Boolean flag = famApp.FamIdentify(ref agentCollection, ref name, SampleModel, REMOTE_ADDR);
```

Comment: The type of namespace 'Collection' does not exists in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' . (Are you missing an assembly reference ? )

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` or somewhere like that

Comment: Cannot convert from  Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection to VBA.Collection .

Comment: So its not Visual Basic, it's Visual Basic for Applications... I can't imagine why one would use VBA type collection, but you can look into VB project `references` and see where this VBA dll is comeing from

Comment: My VBA references are found here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\`

Comment: I have found this directoy : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA . But there is only these dlls . MRT7ENU.DLL , MSO97RT.DLL , QRYINT32.DLL . Which one should I include ?

Comment: Well as far as I imagine, you should find VBA.dll or VBA6.dll. Can you lookup the correct path in VB project references?

Comment: If I add this, I get refereence to VBA, but if I try to use it I get Exception. I suggest fixing VB project to reference VB Collection, and not VBA Collection

Comment: How can I fix VB project to reference VB Collection ? Any resource ?

Comment: Just delete VBA in `References` or use full class name `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` in `FamIdentify` function

Comment: When I try to delte VBA reference I am getting this error . Can't remove control or reference ; in use . WHen I write full class name  Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection , I am getting this error . ""User defined type not defined

Comment: You need to add dll from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Microsof‌​t.VisualBasic.dll`

Comment: can't add a reference to the specified file  .